# Field types in Dynamics Ax

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is it possible to store binary information in a Dynamics field?  For example, I'd like to store an MS Word document inside the Dynamics database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add a container field to the table, then use the [BinData Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa550840.aspx) to read the file and convert the data to a container. For an examples of this, look at how the standard Document handling feature stores files in the database in the table method `DocuValue.writeDocuValue()`, or look at how image files are stored in the `CompanyImage` form.

Comment: Beware that container and memo fields in transaction tables are bad practice due to the extra disk read operations involved. Consider using a separate table to store the document and reference keys. `DocuValue` is such a table, no problem here.