# Axapta: Load and Save file from and to container field

Tags: axapta, x++

I need to customize AX to load an arbitrary file with arbitrary size and save it to database as a container field. I also need to read back from that container field and write the content into a file, which should contain exactly the same file content as before load.

I had tried with BinaryIO, unfortunately with no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826426/field-types-in-dynamics-ax) applies.
Especially you should use the system class `BinData` and the methods `loadFile` and `saveFile` 
.

Example: this job copies the `notepad` program to a temporary directory.

```
static void BinDataTest(Args _args)
{
    BinData b = new BinData();
    Container c;
    b.loadFile(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe");
    info(int2str(b.size()));
    c = b.getData();
    b = new BinData();
    b.setData(c);
    info(int2str(b.size()));
    b.saveFile(@"C:\Temp\notepad.exe");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks Jan, The loading is done to container field (though I do not know whether it contain correct data (just a BLOB?? eventhough what I'm loading is a binary data not an image. Then I tried to save that container field to disk by saveFile - setData, unfortunately the saved file is an empty file with zero byte.

Comment: In the debugger, what is the size of the container BLOB? It should match the size of the file exactly. Answer updated.