# BLOB to Bitmap in axapta

Tags: blob, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have declared a variable as
        `Bitmap image;`
        `Container  storeImg;`

I am storing the image as
    `storeImg+= image;`
the image is stored as `BLOB` type in *container*

Later On when I try to retrieve the image in a Bitmap variable e.g.
    `Bitmap image2;`
    `image2 = conpeek(storeImg,1);`

I get an **"operand mismatch error"**
My question is I have declared the image as bitmap and stored in a container then why the error when I am trying to retrieve the same in a bitmap datatype only?

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Bitmap` extended data type is really a container.

Adding containers gives concatenation which may be (part of) your problem:

```
static void BitmapTest(Args _args)
{
    Bitmap image1 = [1,2,3];
    Bitmap image2 = [7,8,9];
    Container storeImg;
    ;
    storeImg += image1;
    storeImg += image2;
    print conlen(storeImg);
    pause;
}
```

This prints 6, not 2 as you may assume.

Also `blob` and `container` is not the same thing:

```
static void BitmapTest(Args _args)
{
    BinData b = new BinData();
    Bitmap image1 = b.getData();
    Bitmap image2 = b.getData();
    Container storeImg;
    ;
    storeImg += image1;
    storeImg += image2;
    image2 = conpeek(storeImg,1);
    pause;
}
```

This will fail because `storeImg` contains two `blob` values.

Change the assignments to:

```
    storeImg += [image1];
    storeImg += [image2];
```

This will work, because now  `storeImg` contains two `container` values (containing a `blob`).

Also see [Load and Save file from and to container field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207240/axapta-load-and-save-file-from-and-to-container-field)

Comment: thanks alot for the detailed explanation once again. I was thinking to pass the BLOB value just like any other datatype, also i didnt know much abt the similarity betwn container and bitmap(though i noticed the bitmap EDT as bitmap container). Thanks again.